# Finding row that has number instersecting two columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, intersection

Data has three columns. I need to find the row that has the number intersecting between second and third columns. For example, which row has number 15 between second and third column in the data below?

```
a   1   5
b   7   10
c   13  17
d   20  24
```

The ideal result should be

```
c   13  17
```

as it has '15' intersecting that row between second and third column. Is there a way to do it using Python (specifically Python 2.7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([('a', 1, 5), ('b', 7, 10), ('c', 13, 17), ('d', 20, 24)],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

df[(df.col2 < 15) & (df.col3 > 15)]
```

yields...

```
  col1  col2  col3
2    c    13    17
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
  tag  start  end
0   a      1    5
1   b      7   10
2   c     13   17
3   d     20   24

In [8]: df.query('start < 15 < end')
Out[8]: 
  tag  start  end
2   c     13   17
```